# Inheritance with contextlib.contextmanager

Tags: python, contextmanager

Given a class

```
class SomeClass:
    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def on_connection(self, target_terminal, source_terminal):
        ...
        yield
        ...
```

How do you inherit from it?

Comment: Apologies for the self-answer.  I searched StackOverflow for an answer to this question.  When I couldn't find one, I had to actually think about the problem and then decided to post an answer for the next person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to combine the `contextlib.contextmanager` pattern with a `with` block to bring in the superclass' context manager:

```
class SomeDerivedClass(SomeClass):
    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def on_connection(self, target_terminal, source_terminal):
        with super().on_connection(target_terminal, source_terminal):
            ...
            try:
                yield
            finally:
                ...
```